# Given ∃x.¬p(x), use the Fitch System to prove ¬∀x.p(x).

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

What I am thinking was I need two formulas,
AX.p(X) => something
AX.p(X) => ~ something

I guess something maybe is the p(x) and the other is ~p(x) since we was given EX.~p(x)..But actually it can't work for me. And I guess maybe is EX.~p(x) and ~EX.~p(x)..But if I am doing that then the it will go to deadend..so I give up..;(

Wish someone can help me.

For note about EE:
1: EX.p(X)
2: AX.(p(X) => something)
3: something EE1,2
But something cann't have the free variable from p..in this sample, then soemthing cannot including X..so if something is p(X) it cannot use EE, but if p(Y) then can use EE.

Comment: Hint: first prove $\lnot p(x) \vdash \lnot \forall x ~ p(x)$.  Note the $x$ represent different variables.

Comment: Thanks!! slime face ;) @DanielV

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

$1.~\exists X~\lnot p(X)\quad $ Premise

$2.~\quad \lnot p(c)\quad$      Existential Elimination:1, Witness Assumed: $[c]$

$3.~\qquad\forall X~p(X)\quad$ Assumption

$4.~\qquad p(c)\quad$        Universal Elimination:3

$5.~\quad \forall X~p(X) \implies p(c)\quad$ Implication Introduction 3-4

$6.~\qquad\forall X~p(X)\quad$ Assumption

$7.~\qquad\lnot p(c)\quad$ Reiteration:2

$8.~\quad\forall X p(X) \implies \lnot p(c)\quad$ Implication Introduction: 6-7

$9.~\quad\lnot \forall X~p(X)\quad$ Negation Introduction 5,8

$10.~\lnot \forall X~p(X)\quad$ Witness Eliminated 2-9

Answer (score 2):

Given your EE rule, you need to prove $\forall x (\neg p(x) \rightarrow \neg \forall x \ P(x))$, which you do by a universal introduction on $\neg p(x) \rightarrow \forall x \ p(x)$, which on its turn you prove by a conditional Introduction on a subproof that assumes $\neg p(x)$ and derives $\neg \forall x \ p(x)$ .. and the latter you get by a proof by contradiction as you yourself surmised. So:

1. $\exists x \neg p(x)$ Premise
2. $\quad \neg p(x)$ Assumption
3. $\quad \quad \forall x \ p(x)$ Assumption
4. $\quad \quad p(x)$ $\forall$ Elim 3
5. $\quad \forall x \ p(x) \rightarrow p(x)$ $\rightarrow$ Intro 3-4
6. $\quad \quad \forall x \ p(x)$ Assumption
7. $\quad \quad \neg p(x)$ Reiteration 2
8. $\quad \forall x \ p(x) \rightarrow \neg p(x)$ $\rightarrow$ Intro 6-7
9. $\quad \neg \forall x \ p(x)$ $\neg$ Intro 5,8
10. $\neg p(x) \rightarrow \neg \forall x \ p(x)$ $\rightarrow$ Intro 2-9
11. $\forall x (\neg p(x) \rightarrow \neg \forall x \ p(x))$ $\forall$ Intro 10
12. $\neg \forall x \ p(x)$ $\exists$ Elim 1, 11

Comment: How you know that much~!!?? I always stuck at some points and cannot go through...Probably I go into a wrong way.And Thanks again and again~!!

Comment: @tangaqua After years of practice you really start to 'know' all the different patterns :)  So yeah, that took me a long time, so don't feel bad if you're struggling. And I said some time before: you don't have the most user-friendly system either ... so it is not necessarily that you are bad with logic, but just that you have a hard time putting that into this particular proof system.

Comment: By your inspiration, I just solve the other prove by myself~! Hahaha~! Helps me a lot~

Comment: @tangaqua Yay! Good for you!!  :)

Comment: @tangaqua You shouldn't try writing a formal proof until you can write an informal proof first.  Formal proofs are just a language, not an idea.  You have to have the idea (the reason why you think the theorem is true) before you can put the idea into a language.

Comment: @DanielV That's good advice!

Comment: Um there seems to be a missing "$\neg$" in your very first line (premise). =)

Comment: @user21820 Quite!  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @DanielV but without writing down the goal, I mean the formal proof I even don't know where I should start to solve the problem. I am not always just has the idea comes up like you guys. That's sad, but I try to improve ;)